# Tensorflow time series model supported by TFLite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am looking for a decent time series model in tenforflow (1.x or 2.0) that can be used with TFLite. It seems RNN and LSTM lack support. The goal is to predict the next value given n lookback values. Of course, generally, this can be handled. The tricky part is TFLite.

Comment: Yes. LSTM and Batch Normalization ops along with Embedding layer ops are not yet supported by TFLite. Maybe, you can build your custom ops here.